# Make 2 modules in 1 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, mean-stack

I have a `mean-stack` project. In my `index.js`, I have in the end

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
})
module.exports = router;
```

Now I want to treat all the webpages matching `https://localhost:3000/1/addin/*` by `./views/addinIndex.html`, where I expect to refer to different external files and define different modules. Thus, I add another `router.get`:

```
router.get('/1/addin/*', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/addinIndex.html')
})
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
})
module.exports = router;
```

And here is `addinIndex.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <script> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
            console.log("bootstrapped")
        })
        app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router'])
        app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
            $stateProvider
                .state('addinHome1', {
                    url: '/1/addin/home',
                    template: 'addinHome1'
                })
                .state('addinHome2', {
                    url: '/addin/home',
                    template: 'addinHome2'
                })
                .state('addinHome3', {
                    url: '/home',
                    template: 'addinHome3'
                })
        }])
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    abcde
    <ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

However, when I run `https://localhost:3000/1/addin/home`, it shows `abcde` and nothing else, while `bootstrapped` is printed in the console.

Does anyone know what's wrong? May I define an extra `addinIndex.html` like this, given I have already a working `index.html`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It's possible to serve different index based on the route.
But for that you've to remove `#` from url.

To do that follow these steps.

1. We will use the $locationProvider module and set html5Mode to true.

   ```
   // use the HTML5 History API
   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
   ```
2. To link around your application using relative links, you will need to set a  in the  of your document. Add below code in you angular config.

   ```
   <base href="/">
   ```

Comment: Thank you... I did not know that it is related to html5mode, I will try your solution later...